# 15.10 installer: Error installing '...' - trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/validlocale'

Tags: system-installation, locale

During fresh installation procedure I get this error:

```
Error installing /cdrom//pool/main/g/glibc/locales_2.19-18+deb8u2_all.deb
trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/validlocale', which is also in package libc-bin 2.21-0ubuntu4
```

After closing this error, another one pops up saying the installer has crashed

[image: installer crashed, report a bug]

I booted my laptop from a live USB which has iso of Ubuntu 15.10.
I used unetbootin to make the bootable USB.

Comment: Looks like an installer bug to me. No idea, but maybe you could try to install it again with a different language setting?

Comment: The package `locales_2.19-18+deb8u2_all.deb`  belongs to Debian jessie.  It isn't compatible with Ubuntu 15.10.  Are you sure you are using an official Ubuntu ISO image?

Comment: yes I am sure.I download it from official website http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop 2nd link in the page-64 bit

Comment: need to add that I used unetbootin to make bootable usb

Comment: @karel: How does that question relate to such an issue *during system installation*? Please be more careful when you suggest linked question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually in unetbootin. If you start unetbootin from the same version as you are trying to install, there should be no problem.
I tried installing 14.04.4-LTS or 15.10 with a stick made wit unetbootin from 12.04 LTS, and I had the same error.
Since I did not have any system, I tried the Rufus-tool on Windows and that made perfect install stick....